# MongoDB .find() only ObjectId's embedded in an Array.

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I am trying to get only the ObjectId's from One specific Document that is embedded in the projects Array.
Basically I am trying to make a database that will have users and each user will have there own projects.
Thank you !

```
db.users.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5762c0cf2b9a78006373a684"),
    "name" : "seq",
    "pass" : "seq",
    "projects" : [
        {
            "pid" : ObjectId("5762c0ba2b9a78006373a682"),
            "name" : "aaa"
        },
        {
            "pid" : ObjectId("5762c0ba2b9a78006373a683"),
            "name" : "bbb"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5762c28d2b9a78006373a687"),
    "name" : "leq",
    "pass" : "leq",
    "projects" : [
        {
            "pid" : ObjectId("5762c2892b9a78006373a685"),
            "name" : "ccc"
        },
        {
            "pid" : ObjectId("5762c2892b9a78006373a686"),
            "name" : "ddd"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: so you're looking for a query that will return only 1 `pid`?

Comment: @AndreiM. I need all the pid's in this case both the pid's

Comment: so something like this `db.users.find( { }, {projects:1, _id: 0}).pretty()` you need to force omit the _id because it will return otherwise

Comment: what version of mongo do you use?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here. Please edit your question to show the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

let say we want two pids

> {"pid" : ObjectId("5762c0ba2b9a78006373a682")} and 
>   {"pid" : ObjectId("5762c2892b9a78006373a686"),}

and only inner documents

so required response should look like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5762c0ba2b9a78006373a682"),
    "name" : "aaa"
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5762c2892b9a78006373a686"),
    "name" : "ddd"
}
```

Aggregation framework can manipulate documents, match only needed ones and transform inner structure by project phase:

```
var match = {
    $match : {
        "projects.pid" : {
            $in : [ObjectId("5762c0ba2b9a78006373a682"), 
                   ObjectId("5762c2892b9a78006373a686")]
        }
    }
}
var unwind = {
    $unwind : "$projects"
};

// now move array objet as top level object
var project = {
    $project : {
        _id : "$projects.pid",
        name : "$projects.name",
        // list other fields here
    }
}
db.vic.aggregate([match, unwind, match, project])
```